# How to Barcode "-" and space for 3 of 9 barcode in crystal report? (formula)

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have problem in barcoding some strings like "58-04105-01" and "TY 89" in crystal report.

Please help.

Comment: Need more information here to help you..

Comment: basically, I'm using free 3 of 9 barcode and it only works for alphabet numeric combination. Any suggestion for "-" symbol?

Comment: These are all valid characters for Code 39.  What happens when you use them?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using database fields, you can do the following (assuming each number is a separate  field):

```
{dataset.field} & "-" & {dataset.field2}
```